# Error al Actualizar una lista de objetos en linQ

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, linq

Buenas a todos comunidad , tengo un problema que obtengo una lista de objetos, pero ,al querer actualizar la misma lista de objetos que obtengo  me esta marcando error , estoy recorriendo la lista con foreach para que me lea cada objeto de la lista pero no me esta reconociendo , la variable de entrada es el modelo de la clase RolPermiso y el es un metodos post y envío como json la lista de objetos , ¿ cual es mi error?

este es mi repository

```
 public string updateRolPermiso(RolPermiso rp)
        {
            string rpta = "";
            List<RolPermiso> rolPermiso = _condominioContext.RolPermiso.Where(x => x.RolPerCod.Equals(rp.RolPerCod)).ToList();

            foreach (var item in rolPermiso)
            {
                item.RolPerCod = rp.RolPerCod;
                item.RolPerCodRol = rp.RolPerCodRol;
                item.RolPerCodPer = rp.RolPerCodPer;
                item.RolPerEst = rp.RolPerEst;
                item.RolPerFecCre = rp.RolPerFecCre;
                item.RolPerUsuCre = rp.RolPerUsuCre;
                item.RolPerFecMod = rp.RolPerFecMod;
                item.RolPerUsuMod = rp.RolPerUsuMod;
            }
            _condominioContext.SaveChanges();
            rpta = "Los permisos se actualizaron correctamente";
            return rpta;
              
        }
```

este es mi controller

```
[HttpPost("actualizarRolPer")]
        public ActionResult actualizarRolPer([FromBody] RolPermiso rolPermiso)
        {
            IActionResult result = Unauthorized();
            string rpta = _adminService.updateRolPermiso(rolPermiso);
            try
            {
                if (rpta.Equals("Los permisos se actualizaron correctamente"))
                {
                    result = Ok(new { messaje = rpta, error = false, data = new { permisos = rolPermiso } });
                }
                else
                {
                    result = Ok(new { messaje = "No se pudo actualizar los permisos", error = true });
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                result = Ok(new { messaje = "Sé origino un error en el proceso", error = true });
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

el json que envio

```
[
    {
        "rolPerCod": 1,
        "rolPerCodRol": 1,
        "rolPerCodPer": 1,
        "rolPerEst": "0",
        "rolPerFecCre": "2021-05-28T09:59:03.82",
        "rolPerUsuCre": "",
        "rolPerFecMod": null,
        "rolPerUsuMod": null
    },
    {
        "rolPerCod": 2,
        "rolPerCodRol": 1,
        "rolPerCodPer": 1,
        "rolPerEst": "0",
        "rolPerFecCre": "2021-05-28T10:04:59.387",
        "rolPerUsuCre": "",
        "rolPerFecMod": null,
        "rolPerUsuMod": null
    }
]
```

en postman me lanza este error

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-d3cfa013ca4db34ca0d4ec28609d5e22-a89c280de6967a4a-00",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to Condominios.Models.RolPermiso. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

que pasa que el json que está enviando es una colección y en el controlador espera un objeto de la clase `RolPermiso`, pruebe cambiar el json o en el controlador esperar una colección de `RolPermiso` ejemplo (`public ActionResult actualizarRolPer([FromBody] RolPermiso[] rolPermisos)`) ahora si hace esto tiene que iterar sobre esa colección y llamar el método `_adminService.updateRolPermiso(rolPermiso);` para cada elemento de la colección ejemplo:

```
foreach(var rolPermiso in rolePermisos){
_adminService.updateRolPermiso(rolPermiso);
}
```

y entonces mandar una colección de mensajes para cada permiso,

Que yo haría, cambiaría el json y mandara un solo objeto en vez de una colección, Saludos